# Changing a mobile service's running version of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, version, azure-mobile-services

I need to update the version of the NodeJS engine in my mobileservice to support some new functions found in the default libraries. I have tried to update the requirement in the packages.json (root of the service's GIT checkout) with no changes.

This is what it looks like now (I have removed some of the extra details):

```
{
    "main": "server.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.9.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {}
}
```

I need version 0.9.3 or newer. Does the process take this file into consideration? How can I update the version of Node in my mobile service?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK currently Mobile Service is running on 0.8.26 and you cannot change it. There is special WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION app setting to switch in Azure WebSites but it is not possible to save it in Mobile Service app settings.